# Running Battlefield 3 with 2 x 9600gt in SLI

Tags: pc, battlefield-3

I am currently running:

- Quad core Q6600 overclocked to 3.2ghz
- 4GB DDR3 RAM
- 2 x 9600gt 1GB running in an SLI configuration
- MSI Platinum motherboard
- SSD for storage

Will this rig be expected to be capable of running the upcoming Battlefield 3 with reasonable performance or will I need an upgrade?

In an ideal world I'd upgrade the entire rig, but this is not currently possible. If expected performance is quite poor, what suitable graphics card upgrade would this rig accept?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a, "Can I run it?" question.  We don't allow these types of questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Battlefield 3 is expected to have similar requirements as Bad Company 2. [Here](http://bf3blog.com/battlefield-3-system-requirements/) is the official information.

Below i have included the Minimum and Recommmended system requirements. Your 2x9600gt is not quite as powerful as a GTX 460, but it is not that slow either. So if you reduce the settings a little, i think you should do fine. GTX460 scores 23332 points in 3dMark 2006, while 2x9600gt scores 19857 points.

Note that 9600GT does not support DirectX 11, so if BF3 makes good use of that, the effects will be a lot nicer. See the [Crysis 2 Direct X 11 review](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/crysis-2-directx-11-performance,2983.html) for more information on the benefits of DirectX 11.

**Minimum systen**

```
OS: Windows Vista or Windows 7
Processor: Core 2 Duo @ 2.0GHz
RAM: 2GB
Graphic card: DirectX 10 or 11 compatible Nvidia or AMD ATI card.
Graphics card memory: 512 MB
Hard drive: 15 GB for disc version or 10 GB for digital version
```

**Recommended system**

```
OS: Windows 7 64-bit
Processor: Quad-core Intel or AMD CPU
RAM: 4GB
Graphics card: DirectX 11 Nvidia or AMD ATI card, GeForce GTX 460, Radeon Radeon HD 6850
Graphics card memory: 1 GB
Hard drive: 15 GB for disc version or 10 GB for digital version
```

Comment: Great news, thank you for the information. BC2 runs quite well on the rig at the moment so it's sounding promising for my wallet's health. Thanks again.